# WPF .Net Framworke app - Main menu dropdowns disappear immediately on mouseover

Tags: wpf, menu, dropdown

I am going mad with this problem. I have a Window that has a standard  specified that used to work just fine. It has 5 options, the rightmost 2 are immediate Click operations, while the left 3 have single level dropdown submenus.  For some reason they have started disappearing as soon as I move the mouse down from the top level menu that displays them.  Nothing I have tried will make them reappear.  I have loads of other Windows in this app, all of which have similar menus, and they are working fine and behave normally, it is just this one window that is doing this.

I have triple checked the syntax of the menu code in the XAML it is identical to the other windows in terms of closing chevrons etc.

The code is:

```
... 

<Menu
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Height="30" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"            
        Width="428" Opacity="0.5" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="{DynamicResource Black0}" IsHitTestVisible="True" Background="{DynamicResource Black2}">
        <Menu.Items>

            <MenuItem  Header="_Linq Queries" 
                    Margin="5"
                     Width="80" 
                    Foreground="{StaticResource White0}">

                <MenuItem Header="A/c Type 1 Only"
                        Background="Red"
                        Click="Linq1_Click"
                        Foreground="White"
                        IsHitTestVisible="True" 
                        IsCheckable="false"/>
                <MenuItem Header="A/c Type 2 Only"
                    Click="Linq2_Click"
                    Foreground="Black"
                    IsHitTestVisible="True" IsCheckable="False" StaysOpenOnClick="True"/>
                <MenuItem Header="A/c Type 3 Only"
                    Click="Linq3_Click"
                    Foreground="Black"
                    IsCheckable="False" StaysOpenOnClick="True"/>
                <MenuItem Header="A/c Type 4 Only"
                    Click="Linq4_Click"
                    Foreground="#FF971F1F"
                    IsCheckable="False" Background="{DynamicResource Gray3}" StaysOpenOnClick="True"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Multi A/C Holders"
                    Click="Linq5_Click"
                    IsCheckable="False"
                    Foreground="Black"/>
                <Separator />
                <MenuItem Header="Show All Records"
                    Click="Linq6_Click"
                    IsCheckable="False"
                    Foreground="Black"/>
            </MenuItem>


            <MenuItem  Header="Filtering" 
                Width="60" 
                    Foreground="{StaticResource White1}">

                <MenuItem  Header="Trigger My Own Command"
                     Command="{Binding myCommandBinding}"
                    FontWeight="DemiBold"
                    Foreground="{StaticResource Black1}"
                    Background="#00FF00"
                    Style="{StaticResource MenuItemGreen}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                    Width="290"
                    Margin="2"/>
                <!--<Button Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="4" Command="{Binding InformationCommand}">Info</Button>-->
            </MenuItem>

            <MenuItem  Header="Options" 
                    Click="Options_Click"
                    Width="50" 
                    Foreground="{StaticResource White2}">

                <MenuItem  Header="Export Bank Account Db => CSV"
                    Click="ExportBankCSV_Click"
                    FontWeight="DemiBold"
                    Foreground="{StaticResource Black1}"
                    Background="#00FF00"
                    Style="{StaticResource MenuItemGreen}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                    Width="290"
                    Margin="2"/>
                <MenuItem  Header="Export Customers Db => CSV"
                    Click="ExportCustCSV_Click"
                    FontWeight="DemiBold"
                    Foreground="{StaticResource Black1}"
                    Background="#00FF00"
                    Style="{StaticResource MenuItemGreen}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                    Width="290"
                    Margin="2"                   />
                <MenuItem  Header="Export Details Db => CSV"
                    Click="ExportDetCSV_Click"
                    FontWeight="DemiBold"
                    Foreground="{StaticResource Black1}"
                    Background="#00FF00"
                    Style="{StaticResource MenuItemGreen}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                    Width="290"
                    Margin="2"/>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem  Header="Import Bank Account Db from CSV"
                    Click="ImportBankCSV_Click"
                    FontWeight="DemiBold"
                    Background="#FF0000"
                    Foreground="White"
                    Style="{StaticResource MenuItemRed}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                    Width="290"
                    Margin="2"
                    />
                <MenuItem  Header="Import Customers Db from CSV"
                    Click="ImportCustCSV_Click"
                    FontWeight="DemiBold"
                    Foreground="White"
                    Background="#FF0000"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                    Style="{StaticResource MenuItemRed}"
                    Width="290"
                    Margin="2"
                    />
                <MenuItem  Header="Import Details Db from CSV"
                    Click="ImportDetCSV_Click"
                    FontWeight="DemiBold"
                    Foreground="White"
                    Background="#FF0000"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                    Style="{StaticResource MenuItemRed}"
                    Width="290"
                    Margin="2"
                    />

            </MenuItem>
        </Menu.Items>
```

I have spent 2 days searching the web for a solution for this, but most issues seem to be with web page main menus, not App style programs.

I hope somebody can spot what is going on. I have tried different IsHitTextVisible settings, Focusable settings etc, nothing changes this infuriating behaviour ?

Yes Emmanuelle, here is very much the same menu, but from another window very similar to the problem window but it works just fine :

```
    <!--#region Menu Bar-->
    <Menu           
        Background="Transparent"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Height="30" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Width="auto">

        <MenuItem  Header="_Linq Queries" 
                Margin="5"
                 Width="80" 
                Foreground="{StaticResource White0}">
            <MenuItem Header="A/c Type 1 Only"
                    Background="#35F6FB" 
                    Click="Linq1_Click"
                    Foreground="Black"
                    IsCheckable="false"/>
            <MenuItem Header="A/c Type 2 Only"
                Background="#35F6FB" 
                Click="Linq2_Click"
                Foreground="Black"
                IsCheckable="False"/>
            <MenuItem Header="A/c Type 3 Only"
                Background="#35F6FB" 
                Click="Linq3_Click"
                Foreground="Black"
                IsCheckable="False"/>
            <MenuItem Header="A/c Type 4 Only"
                Background="#35F6FB" 
                Click="Linq4_Click"
                Foreground="Black"
                IsCheckable="False"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Multi A/C Holders"
                Background="#35F6FB" 
                Click="Linq5_Click"
                IsCheckable="False"
                Foreground="Black"/>
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="Show All Records"
                Background="#35F6FB" 
                Click="Linq6_Click"
                IsCheckable="False"
                Foreground="Black"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Create 'Join' of Bank and Details"
                Background="#35F6FB"
                Click="bankjoin_Click"
                    IsCheckable="false"
            Foreground="Black"/>
        </MenuItem>

        <MenuItem  Header="Filtering" 
            Width="60" 
                Foreground="{StaticResource White1}">

            <MenuItem  Header="Trigger My Own Command"
                 Command="{Binding myCommandBinding}"
                FontWeight="DemiBold"
                Foreground="{StaticResource Black1}"
                Background="#00FF00"
                Style="{StaticResource MenuItemGreen}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                Width="290"
                Margin="2"/>
            <!--<Button Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="4" Command="{Binding InformationCommand}">Info</Button>-->
        </MenuItem>
        
        <MenuItem  Header="Options" 
                Click="Options_Click"
                Width="50" 
                Foreground="{StaticResource White2}">

            <MenuItem  Header="Export Bank Account Db => CSV"
                Click="ExportBankCSV_Click"
                FontWeight="DemiBold"
                Foreground="{StaticResource Black1}"
                Background="#00FF00"
                Style="{StaticResource MenuItemGreen}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                Width="290"
                Margin="2"/>
            <MenuItem  Header="Export Customers Db => CSV"
                Click="ExportCustCSV_Click"
                FontWeight="DemiBold"
                Foreground="{StaticResource Black1}"
                Background="#00FF00"
                Style="{StaticResource MenuItemGreen}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                Width="290"
                Margin="2"                   />
            <MenuItem  Header="Export Details Db => CSV"
                Click="ExportDetCSV_Click"
                FontWeight="DemiBold"
                Foreground="{StaticResource Black1}"
                Background="#00FF00"
                Style="{StaticResource MenuItemGreen}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                Width="290"
                Margin="2"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem  Header="Import Bank Account Db from CSV"
                Click="ImportBankCSV_Click"
                FontWeight="DemiBold"
                Background="#FF0000"
                Foreground="White"
                Style="{StaticResource MenuItemRed}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                Width="290"
                Margin="2"
                />
            <MenuItem  Header="Import Customers Db from CSV"
                Click="ImportCustCSV_Click"
                FontWeight="DemiBold"
                Foreground="White"
                Background="#FF0000"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                Style="{StaticResource MenuItemRed}"
                Width="290"
                Margin="2"
                />
            <MenuItem  Header="Import Details Db from CSV"
                Click="ImportDetCSV_Click"
                FontWeight="DemiBold"
                Foreground="White"
                Background="#FF0000"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                Style="{StaticResource MenuItemRed}"
                Width="290"
                Margin="2"
                />

        </MenuItem>

        <MenuItem  Header="Drag / Drop"
            Click="Drag_Click"
             IsTabStop="False"
            Width="81"
            Foreground="{StaticResource White1}">
        </MenuItem>


        <MenuItem  Header="Close Viewer..."
                Click="Exit_Click"
                 FontWeight="SemiBold"
                 Margin="2,0"
                Width="97"
                Foreground="{StaticResource White1}"/>
    </Menu>
```

I have even copied the menu from the working window into this one - same result, so it does not appear to be the Menu code ?

My window is this -

```
<Window x:Class="WPFPages.SqlDbViewer"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:data="clr-namespace:WPFPages"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
  DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    MinHeight="450"
    MinWidth="867"
    Loaded="OnWindowLoaded" 
    PreviewKeyDown="Window_PreviewKeyDown"
    Title="Database Edit/View Utility" 
    Height="450" Width="867"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Closed="Window_Closed"
    WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow">
```

Nothing odd in there ??

I just noticed that by using the magnifier, I CAN mouse down the enclosing rectangle of the PopUpRow itself, it is as soon as I touch the actual MenuItem that it disappears.  So it is the MenuItem that is sensitive and causing the closure of the entire popup

Even weirder, by moving the cursor down the side of the menu very carefully outside the items, I find I *can* mouseover the seperator, but not any of the items. !

Finally, I have tried commenting out the entire menuitem style MenuItemGreen used on the first 3 items of the Options menu, but it makes no difference at all.  I just have no idea what is going on here ?

I am not sure what resources you would like to see ?  As above, I have commented out all Menu/Menuitem Styles etc in this particular file,  The other resources (Menu colors like MenuItemGreen) are all used by the other windows that have  fully working menus, so I suspect they cannot be effecting just this window ?

I have just removed all <Style and Background/foreground {Staticresource} from the entire menu system in this window, but it still does not work correctly.  They are nowjust the basic menu commands throughout, but still no luck

Please clarify what else will help you ?

This is what a good and the bad menu look like ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdaxb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGOHj.png)

Comment: Can you provide a working sample of another menu that is working?

Comment: Can you also provide the resources? I suspect there is the problem.